# Did the original Shadowgate for the Macintosh (1987) not have "take" or "leave" command?

Tags: apple-macintosh, nes

I'm very familiar with what I consider to be the "real" version of Shadowgate -- the NES port. Today, I noticed this screenshot from the actual original:

[image: Macintosh Shadowgate screenshot]

There is no "take" or "leave" command, used constantly in the NES version.

What's with that? How do you take objects/items in the original? And how are they dropped (rather than "used")? Speaking of "using", there is no "use" command either...

Comment: I don't know Shadowguard, but on other Mac games with this engine (specifically, Deja Vu and Uninvited), you drag and drop items from scene to inventory and vice versa to take or drop them.

Answer (score 14):

From the [Shadowgate manual for Windows 3.1 and Macintosh Plus:](https://www.mocagh.org/mindscape/shadowgate-alt-manual.pdf)

> Objects that you would expect to be easily moved - such as torches, swords and coins - can be *dragged* and placed into the Inventory. Large objects such as fortresses, fountains, and trees which cannot be dragged cannot be placed into the Inventory. You will be alerted when you have too much to carry with you in your Inventory.
>
> To drag an object into your Inventory:
>
> 1. With the mouse, point to the object you wish to move.
> 2. Press the mouse button.
> 3. While holding the button down, move the object into the window.
> 4. When the item is inside the window, release the mouse button. If you are allowed to take the object with you, it will remain in the window.

The manual also lists `Operate` as the command to use an object on another object. The example given is using a key on a locked door.

Comment: Reminds me of how the control scheme the Angry Video Game Nerd lambastes in [Dark Castle](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dark-castle) is also a gamepad port of a very mouse-native interaction paradigm that originated on B&W Macintosh.